# Number occurrence counter in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I am fairly new to programming and have been working on a program to count the number of times every value from 0-9 occurs in a string of numbers (this program must use a function and main function that calls it). If a user enters the numbers 123512378, I want it to tell me 1 occurs 2 times 2 occurs 2 times... 8 occurs 1 time etc. Right now I am trying to pass a string into a function then return a list with the number of occurrences in order. However mine just returns the empty list I generated at the start. Here is my code:

```
def countdigits(aString,Result):
  countValue=0
  while countValue>=9:
    Result[countValue]=(aString.count(str(countValue)))
    countValue=countValue+1
  return Result

def main():
  emptyList = 10 * [0]
  numbers=str(input("Pleas enter a string of numbers: "))
  print(countdigits(numbers,emptyList))

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `while countValue<=9:`. You used a `>=`.

Comment: Hahaha thank you very much,  I went over this countless times and kept reading > as less than

Comment: Better yet, use `for countValue in range(10)`.

Comment: Thank you too, I suppose a for loop would be more logical here

Answer (score 1):

Instead of while you can just use

```
for i in range(10): 
    Result[i]=(aString.count(str(i)))
```

or simply

```
return [aString.count(str(i)) for i in range(10)]
```

But this looks a very in-efficient way of doing this (**see edit below**), you are looping 10 times (aString.count will have to search thru whole string), but you can count by just looping once and counting as you go e.g.

```
import collections
def countdigits(aString):
  count_map = collections.defaultdict(int)
  for c in aString:
      count_map[c] += 1
  return count_map

print countdigits("123456789")
```

output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'1': 1, '3': 1, '2': 1, '5': 1, '4': 1, '7': 1, '6': 1, '9': 1, '8': 1})
```

If you want it can be easily converted to array like `Result` but I see no advantage in that

Edit:
Looks like second version should be fast as it loops once but it is not, `list.count` is in C and is super fast and will do fast search, but looping in python is too slow, so timeit show who is is the real winner

```
import collections

def countdigits1(aString):
    return [aString.count(str(i)) for i in range(10)]

def countdigits2(aString):
    count_map = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for c in aString:
        count_map[c] += 1
    return count_map

import timeit
text = "0123456789"*10
print timeit.timeit('countdigits1("%s")'%text, setup="from __main__ import countdigits1", 
                    number=10000)
print timeit.timeit('countdigits2("%s")'%text, setup="from __main__ import countdigits2", 
                    number=10000)
```

output:

```
0.106333017349
0.952333927155
```

Second version is more than 9 times slower.

Comment: You can also use `collections.Counter`, which does all this.